# Get model id from route/url

Tags: laravel

I have a user, event and offer model. A user can make an event
and then another user can make an offer for that event. But now I don't know how to get event id in store method for offer

I get error `event_id not defined`.

When i click on make offer the show view opens for that event and i have the event model in that view...and on that view there is a form to submit offer and i don't know how to get that event id

when i do `dd($request->all());` there are only variables from that form

and what i need is the id of that event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `store()` method you need to add hidden input to the form, for example:

```
{!! Form::hidden('event_id', $event->id) !!}
```

And then get the data:

```
$event_id = $request->event_id;
```

Comment: It cannot be manipulated if you're securing your application properly, this is the best way to do it.

Comment: how can i validate that or check if the event_id is ok

Comment: i will ask a new question for this!