# How to check if hidden form field corresponds to Model id

Tags: laravel

This is my previous question [Get model id from route/url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144792/get-model-id-from-route-url) and the solution was very smart, however i am afraid of manipulation of this

```
{!! Form::hidden('event_id', $event->id) !!}
```

A user AntoineB has said : " It cannot be manipulated if you're securing your application properly, this is the best way to do it."

What can i do to secure my app from manipulating this field and to check if it corresponds to the event id that user actually clicked?
How to check this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented before you can't as all event_id on your website are visible to all users that can use console in browser.

What you can do is encode/encrypt your event_id (Laravel provides encryption)

```
{!! Form::hidden('event_id', encrypt($event->id)) !!}
```

And when you send POST/GET on server side

```
$decrypted_event_id = (int)decrypt($request->input('event_id'));

$event = Event::find($decrypted_event_id);
```

Also you could make restrictions for specific user for particular event_ids
But encypting will hide the actual value of ID
Encrypting doesnt protects you but it makes harder for user to understand what ID your event has.

This is alternative 3rd party library for hash ids [click](http://hashids.org/php/) you may use this if dont like long character of laravel encryption

Comment: i am using middleware for restricting the users so that part is secure....but that user who has access to make an offer for this event....he could theoretically change the hidden field value through browser...so maybe this encrypt and decrypt  could be the solution

Comment: If you already restrict other user for particular event, and afraid of allowed user to make changes to a form then I think yes encrypting values may help as other user don't have access to it

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... What?

```
$request->event_id
```

Comment: i mean the user can make an offer and in that form change the event_id from 2 to 3 for example and that offer would be connected to wrong event....i need to prevent this from happening

Comment: @lewis4u you can't as all event id on your website are visible to user that can use `console` in browser

Comment: i was thinking somehow to compare the event_id from the route with the event_id from FORM and if they match then it is not manipulated...and if they not match the id is manipulated, but i don't know how to do it

Comment: You should use validation, or policy, to determine if user can access that event_id.

Comment: For example: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#writing-policies

Comment: @lewis4u see my answer